# Cordova iOS onResume firing at startup and crashing app

Tags: jquery, ios, cordova, events

I'm currently just building for iOS 8+ and I'm testing on an iPhone 6, and 6S+ in the emulator. I'm using the command line to build and run, and I'm using the Cordova CLI. I've also dipped into XCode a few times to check capabilities, or fix provisioning issues.

This isn't the first app I've build using Cordova, and I've previously been able to use the resume event without issue.

I'm using `document.addEventListener("resume", onResume(), false);` to fire certain functions when my app resumes. However this function is firing on first launch, and not firing at all on startup. It seems to be anytime the resume function fires it crashes my app.

I've reduced my app down to bare bones, nothing is happening in the onResume function now except the following:

```
function onResume() {
    setTimeout(function(){
        console.log('App resumed');
    },0);   
}
```

Going a little out of my mind here. I have the following plugins installed.

- com.telerik.plugins.healthkit 0.4.2 "HealthKit"
- cordova-plugin-console 1.0.2 "Console"
- cordova-plugin-splashscreen 3.1.0 "Splashscreen"
- cordova-plugin-statusbar 2.1.1 "StatusBar"
- cordova-plugin-webserver 1.0.3 "CordovaWebServer"
- cordova-plugin-whitelist 1.2.1 "Whitelist"

Comment: Please **answer the following questions in your post**. Since this appears to be your first post on this subject. Is this your first hybrid App?
What is your target platform and their target versions: Android 4,5,6? iOS 7,8,9? Are you using [CLI, SDK or Build](https://github.com/jessemonroy650/top-phonegap-mistakes/blob/master/new-to-Phonegap.md#001) ? Please do not assume the answer, please read the link. Once you have answer the question *in the post*, respond in the comments so I know you have added information to the post.

Comment: @JesseMonroy650 thanks for your reply. I've updated my post.

Comment: I've just put the event code back in place, and now it's working. I've not idea what I'd done before to cause it not to work, but clearly must have been a problem of my own making. @JesseMonroy650 thank you for your help, and sorry to have wasted your time.

Comment: Are you really using `document.addEventListener("resume", onResume(), false); ` ? It should be `document.addEventListener("resume", onResume, false);`

Comment: @JesseMonroy650 ah ha! I'm not using the brackets, but perhaps I was doing that when I was having the problem. If that indeed was the issue it would explain a lot. Thank you :) I'm putting this one down to lack of sleep.

Comment: It' okay. We are all subject to those types of errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Managed to fix this problem, though not sure what I'd done wrong. I can only assume I must have had the wrong event name in place, or in my attempts to fix it I'd added another problem before fixing the previous one. Either way something I'd done wrong had caused the issue.

Things to check yourself:

- Your `document.addEventListener('resume', onResume, false);` event listener is in code run **after device ready** has fired.
- The function you are calling doesn't include the (). E.g. `onResume`, not `onResume()`.
- You've only included a function name and nothing else in the resume event listener.
- The function you're calling includes a setTimeout of 0ms to get around iOS quirks.
- You've spelled your functions and resume event correctly.